# Hiding Elements in an Accordion

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I'm making a product image that displays features on hover. It will be using tooltips in the desktop version and then a modified accordion on mobile. I need some guidance on the mobile version because I've been cracking at it for days with little progress.

I added a little custom JS to accomplish toggling an accordion where the "button" for each panel is located in a separate div.

At the moment, the "buttons" are working correctly on mobile, but the other panels don't disappear when another button is clicked. That's what I'd like some thoughts on.
Be sure to view in a mobile window. Here's my code:

UPDATE: Corrected a formatting bug in the test code and added comments to JS and HTML.

SOLVED: I solved my own problem. First, I rearranged my HTML so that all panels were child elements of the same div. Then I used the following javascript to hide siblings and show the targeted element on click.

```
if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 1024) {
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".ul.one").click(function() {
      $("#panel-1").show();
      $("#panel-1")
        .siblings()
        .hide();
    });
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-frog-f4l06)

Comment: Hey, your code example is not working properly, could you please improve it and some comments in code to help reading it.

Comment: Great formatting on your first question myth! Props. However, if you resolve your own question you should really add your solution as an answer. Just remove the "SOLVED: " section and add it as an answer to your own question. Plus you can get upvotes and such on your answer, which adds to your account credibility.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: I solved my own problem. First, I rearranged my HTML so that all panels were child elements of the same div. Then I used the following javascript to hide siblings and show the targeted element on click.

```
if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 1024) {
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(".ul.one").click(function() {
$("#panel-1").show();
$("#panel-1")
.siblings()
.hide();
});
```